# No Access Control Allow Origin header

Tags: google-maps-api-3, cors

I'm trying to load the markers with a JSON file (uncommenting your commented code) but I'm not having any success. It is working with the markers hardcoded in the javascript but not when reading the file.

Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. file:///C:/Users/dacosts/workspace/mappingdash/universities.json

Any ideas?

```
var map;
var icon = "http://path/to/icon.png";
//var json = "http://path/to/universities.json";
var json = "universities.json";
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
function initialize() {

    var mapProp = {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(52.4550, -3.3833), //LLANDRINDOD WELLS
        zoom : 7,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);

    $.getJSON("universities.json", function(json1) {

        /*var json1 = {
            "universities": [
                {
                    "title": "Aberystwyth University",
                    "website": "www.aber.ac.uk",
                    "phone": "+44 (0)1970 623 111",
                    "lat": 52.415524,
                    "lng": -4.063066},
                {
                    "title": "Bangor University",
                    "website": "www.bangor.ac.uk",
                    "phone": "+44 (0)1248 351 151",
                    "lat": 53.229520,
                    "lng": -4.129987},
                {
                    "title": "Cardiff Metropolitan University",
                    "website": "www.cardiffmet.ac.uk",
                    "phone": "+44 (0)2920 416 138",
                    "lat": 51.482708,
                    "lng": -3.165881}
            ]
        };*/
        $.each(json1.universities, function(key, data) {

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : latLng,
                map : map,
                // icon: icon,
                title : data.title
            }
        );

            var details = data.website + ", " + data.phone + ".";

            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, details);

        }
    );

    });

}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Here is the data

```
universities: [
      {  
         "title":"Aberystwyth University",
         "website":"www.aber.ac.uk",
         "phone":"+44 (0)1970 623 111",
         "lat":52.415524,
         "lng":-4.063066
      },
      {  
         "title":"Bangor University",
         "website":"www.bangor.ac.uk",
         "phone":"+44 (0)1248 351 151",
         "lat":53.229520,
         "lng":-4.129987
      },
      {  
         "title":"Cardiff Metropolitan University",
         "website":"www.cardiffmet.ac.uk",
         "phone":"+44 (0)2920 416 138",
         "lat":51.482708,
         "lng":-3.165881
      }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are using Chrome. It has restrictions concerning AJAX requests on local resources.

If you want to continue testing without any server you need to use different browser, for example Firefox.

You can also setup a temporary http server for developement and use it to access your website.

There is a possible workaround for Chrome: you would need to start it with the flag `--allow-file-access-from-files`. Make sure you are using it only for developement purposes to avoid safety risks.

**Worth reading**

- [Wikipedia: Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)
- [Wikipedia: Cross-origin Resource
  Sharing (CORS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
- [Chrome flags reference](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#allow-file-access-from-files)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am using Chrome, I only have access to IE 9 or Chrome 31.0.1650.63. 
Is there a workaround? to either browser?